# MongoDB not connecting using Heroku CLI

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku-cli

I recently started learning NodeJS. I have completed my project and deploying it on Heroku. While connecting MongoDB to Heroku i got the following error

[image: Error Image]

I don't know why this URL is considered as the file path.

Comment: I recommend giving Render (where I work) a try. You can use MongoDB Atlas: https://render.com/docs/connect-to-mongodb-atlas or run mongo on a Render disk to get a persistent/stateful db without buying an add-on https://render.com/docs/deploy-mongodb . This is a nice tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l134cBAJCuc

Answer (score 0):

Do you add config vars in the Heroku setting[If you have some env file]? Add key-value pattern and deploy again. Hope it will work.
[image: Heroku config vars]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i am familiar with this method. I want to know why Heroku CLI
is considering link as file path as shown in image.